# Recalculate fields value using ArcPy and Calculate Field tool?

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator

Im not sure how to pass through a list of fields within the calculate field tool.I have a list of fields and each of them need to be divided by 1000.
My code is as follows:

```
import arcpy
shp = r"m\team.shp"
fields = arcpy.ListFields(shp, "*qty")
for f in fields:
    print f.name
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp, f, "f/1000", "PYTHON")
```

Comment: You do not say how many fields you have but I suspect that if it is more than a few then using `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` to do them all in one pass will be the way to go.

Comment: How do I use the updatecursor.da to achieve the same objective? Is this a far quicker way of updating rows?

Comment: Check out the samples in the help at http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm I suspect that the more fields you have the better it will be to use arcpy.da.UpdateCursor().  For one, or maybe a few fields I suspect CalculateField may be quicker but I have not performance timed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to pass your field name `f.name` as the name of the field, and then add that to your expression as well.  In the field calculator you need to surround your field name with exclamation marks e.g. `!myfield!`

I think something like this should work:

```
import arcpy
shp = r"m\team.shp"
fields = arcpy.ListFields(shp, "*qty")
for f in fields:
    print f.name
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(shp, f.name, "!{}!/1000".format(f.name), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

**NOTE:** Be aware that you are overwriting your existing field value with the new value, not calculating into a new field.

Comment: Just as an aside, I have never seen the use of {}. Is that for formatting text? Or is that an easier way to pass values through expressions and so on?

Comment: @Zahir_Ibrahim It's Python string formatting: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples